# how to access the class css properties from an attribute directive associated with the same element

Tags: javascript, css, angular

Here is the component template

```
template: `<h1 class = "dragStyle" [drag] = "true">DRAG THIS ELEMENT</h1>`,
styles : [`
    .dragStyle{
        margin : 12px;
    }`
]
```

Here is the constructor of [drag] attribute directive-

```
constructor(
    private _el: ElementRef, 
    private _renderer : Renderer,
    @Attribute('class') type : string) {
        console.log(type);
```

I need to access the value of margin property associated with the dragStyle class for some computations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if what you are to do 'inject the css class object into the constructor' is possible. But,since you only require the computed css property, why don't you use [getComputedStyle()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getcomputedstyle.asp) ?

In your example,

```
@Directive({
  selector:'[drag]' 
})
export class DragDirective{
  @Input() drag:boolean;
  constructor(
    private _el: ElementRef, 
    private _renderer : Renderer,
    @Attribute('class') type : string) {
        console.log(type);
  }
  ngOnInit(){
    let margin = getComputedStyle(this._el.nativeElement).getPropertyValue('margin');
    console.log(margin);
  }
}
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TBCpXct7vUG1qcr0RMdc?p=preview)

Comment: @shiv glad I could help